# GNU parallel to control concurrency when spawning bash scripts from node.js

Tags: node.js, bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I'm using `Node.JS` with `child_process` to spawn bash processes.

I'm using [pdftotext](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/pdftotext.htm) to extract the text of **10k+** files. To control concurrences, I'm using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Code:

```
let spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
let async = require('async');
let files = [
  {
    path: 'path_for_file'
    ...
  },
  ...
];
let maxNumber = 5;

async.mapLimit(files, maxNumber, (file, callback) => {
  let process = child_process.spawn('pdftotext', [
    "-layout",
    "-enc",
    "UTF-8",
    file.path,
    "-"
  ]);
  let result = '';
  let error = '';

  process.stdout.on('data', function(chunk) {
    result += chunk.toString();
  });

  process.stderr.on('error', function(chunk) {
    error += chunk.toString();
  });

  process.on('close', function(data) {
    if (error) {
      return callback(error, null);
    }
    callback(null, result);
  });


}, function(error, files) {
  if (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }

  console.log(files);
});
```

This is causing almost CPU overloading, as u can see here:

[image]

My question is: If i replace async by [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), it will work? GNU parallel will manage the concurrency for me??

If i remove the async, node.js will break because in some point the CPU can't manage to many processes (if i understood correctly)... Can GNU parallel avoid that?

Thanks.

---

UPDATE

This two are different questions. One is about CPU bound, other is about replacing async by gnu parallel for increase performance. How in the hell this is a dup?

Comment: Almost but not quite overloading your CPU is a good thing, no?  That means you are using the capacity instead of idling.

Comment: Please delete this or your previous version of this Q :  [I/O bound and CPU bound](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945596/i-o-bound-and-cpu-bound) . Agree with @tripleee, 95% CPU is a good thing. Your "job" will get done 10x faster than if your CPU was 9.5%, right? Good luck.

Comment: This two are different questions. One is about CPU bound, other is about replacing async by gnu parallel for increase performance. How in the hell this is a dup?

Comment: About the 95%. Is it a good thing? What is CPU overloading? 100%?